# creating ts_vector with fields from different table in trigger

Tags: postgresql

I need to create trigger that puts data into tsv_vector from joined tables. I've created trigger that works with main table, but I m not sure how to handle other tables in nice way.
I was thinking about doing select to get the column, but it doesnt work and even, if it did it looks ugly. Also I need to get columns from multiple tables not only one.

```
create function custom_function()
    returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as $$
begin
    new.tsv := to_tsvector(new.name || '' || new.source_id || '' ||
                    select column_name from main_table join second_table on 
                                  main_table.detail_id = second_table.id
                                       where main_table.id = new.id );
    RETURN new;
END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a BEFORE trigger, then main_table.detail_id probably doesn't exist yet at the time it runs.  Use new.detail_id instead and drop the join.  It will also be slightly less ugly.